# Validate Customer credentials in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I'm trying to make a login of a user externally in PHP.

Need to know which class should be used in Magento 2 to validate by Email & password and once validated, open the session.

I'm dealing with `CustomerRepository` Class, where there is a function that's supposed fetch a Customer by Email and returns a `CustomerModel` Object but no success. The idea is to get the Model from such user and in case the Model has data, get the password and compare.

```
$this->answer = $this->customer_Repository->get("pepe1@pepe.com");
```

When I print in console the answer, it's empty.

I do not find anything related to this topic. Is There any Class that makes this operation directly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface::authenticate()` method call will help you to validate email as well as password. You may also want to check implementation of the `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost::execute()` method and how session is prepared in case of success authentication.

Comment: I can not figure out how i can implement both, the Interface & class to make it work. I'm a little confused.